# Gurobi: Constraints on decision variables in a multi period scenario

Tags: python, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I have the following parameters:

```
period = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
facility = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5']
```

I have declared a binary decision variable as follows:

```
X_f = m.addVars(facility, period, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="X_f")
```

In a multi period facility location problem, I have the following constraints:

- for every facility, if X_f have the boolean value of 0 in period 0, it remains 0 for all of the periods
- for every facility, if X_f has the boolean value 1 in period 0, then it remains 1 for all of the periods

Basically, it means that once a facility has been opened in period 0, it should not be closed; and if a facility is closed in period 0, then it should remain closed.

I tried to implement this as follows:

```
for f in facility:
    if X_f[f, 0].X == 0:
        m.addConstrs((X_f[f, t+1] == 0 for t in range(0, 11)))

    if X_f[f, 0].X == 1:
        m.addConstrs((X_f[f, t+1] == 1 for t in range(0, 11)))

m.optimize()
```

However, I get the error `AttributeError: Index out of range for attribute 'X'`

I understand this is due to the fact that `X_f[f, 0].X` only has value after the optimization has run.
Is there another way to implement this constraint in a multi period setting?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the value of the decision variable before the solve. So, `X_f[f, 0].X` will not work before the solve. You can use indicator constraints to meet your purpose.
https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_ggc_indicator.html

Please see the below listing:

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

period = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
facility = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5']

m = gp.Model("")

X_f = m.addVars(facility, period, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="X_f")


for f in facility:
    # if X_f[f, 0] == 0, then enforce the constraint that X_f[f, 1] + .. + X_f[f, 11] == 0. 
    m.addGenConstrIndicator(X_f[f, 0], 0, gp.quicksum(X_f[f, i] for i in range(1, max(period) + 1)) == 0)
    # if X_f[f, 0] == 1, then enforce the constraint that X_f[f, 1] + .. + X_f[f, 11] == 11.
    m.addGenConstrIndicator(X_f[f, 0], 1, gp.quicksum(X_f[f, i] for i in range(1, max(period) + 1)) == len(range(1, max(period) + 1)))
    
    
# check : fix X_f["f1", 0] == 0, now, X_f["f1", 1] + .. + X_f["f1", 11] should be 0
m.setAttr("LB", X_f["f1", 0], 0)
m.setAttr("UB", X_f["f1", 0], 0)

# similar to above you can set X_f["f1", 0] == 1, and then X_f["f1", 1] + .. + X_f["f1", 11] should be 11
# m.setAttr("LB", X_f["f1", 0], 1)
# m.setAttr("UB", X_f["f1", 0], 1)

m.optimize()

print(X_f["f1", 0].X) # X_f["f1", 0] was set to zero
sum([X_f["f1", i].X for i in range(1, max(period) + 1)]) # Now, X_f["f1", 1] + .. + X_f["f1", 11] == 0
```